# Wordpress theme looks different in customize and live modes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I got tasked with fixing problems on my company's Wordpress instance. Since I'm novice when it comes to Wordpress and PHP I am sure that I am missing something trivial; problem I am having is that pages look different in preview and when viewed directly. For example, here is what part of HTML that gets rendered in live preview (for site header):

```
<header role="banner" class="clearfix" id="site-header">
    <div class="container">

        <!-- #logo -->
        <div id="logo">
            <h1>
                <a href="http://example.com" title="My Site">My Site</a>
            </h1>  
        </div>
        <!-- /#logo -->
        <!-- #primary-nav -->
        <nav class="clearfix" role="navigation" id="primary-nav">
        </nav>
        <!-- #primary-nav -->

    </div>
</header>
```

However, when I visit site directly (go to http://example.com), I get following HTML in that part:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1>
            <a href="http://example.com" title="My Site">My Site</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting similar behavior when trying different themes. Thus, I'm suspecting something may be wrong with installation of Wordpress... however, I can't just re-install everything - I've inherited this Wordpress instance and must stick with it.

I have no problem with modifying php files and HTML - would just appreciate if someone more experienced with Wordpress would tell me where I should start looking. php files? CDN plugins?

**EDIT:**
Here is header.php from theme:

```
<!-- #header -->
<header id="site-header" class="clearfix" role="banner">
<div class="container">

<!-- #logo -->
  <div id="logo">
    <?php if (is_front_page()) { ?><h1><?php } ?>
      <a title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
      <?php if (of_get_option('st_logo')) { ?>
      <img alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" src="<?php echo of_get_option('st_logo'); ?>">
      <?php } else { ?>
      <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
      <?php } ?>
      </a>
     <?php if (is_front_page()) { ?></h1><?php } ?>
  </div>
<!-- /#logo -->
<!-- #primary-nav -->
<nav id="primary-nav" role="navigation" class="clearfix">
  <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary-nav' ) ) { ?>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary-nav', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav sf-menu clearfix' )); ?>
  <?php } ?>
  </nav>
<!-- #primary-nav -->

</div>
</header>
<!-- /#header -->
```

Comment: What's the php in your header.php file that renders this section? I have noticed some differences in preview vs live mode myself, but this seems different than what I've seen.

Comment: @cale_b Since this "broken" behavior can be reproduced regardless of theme, I'm 90% sure it's not fault of php pages. Rather it must be how "live site pages" are rendered... just I don't know if I can find setting for that. That being said, I'll edit the question to include header.php.

Comment: Agreed. Was just asking for my own curiousity more than anything.  The **preview** is the culprit - some things just don't work right there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I resolved it by changing the settings that were not displaying properly to something else (such as un-checking a checked box), publishing it, and then changing it back and publishing again. I'm guessing there was some mis-match somewhere between something cache and something database and this was a quick way to force them to match up again.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue but rather I had the desired result in the customize preview but not in the actual site. I tried a variety of things in the themes code but sadly I think it just came down to a hard refresh of my customizer and page tabs (ctrl+F5 in chrome) then tweaking the slider and publishing.